# UITabBarController temporarily missing item title and image in More Navigation Controller

Tags: ios, ios4, uiviewcontroller, uitabbarcontroller, uitabbaritem

"Has this ever happened to you?"

(Note: The following is ARC-friendly code, hence no `autorelease` call or `retain`/`release` pairs.)

```
#pragma mark - UIViewController

- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil {
    // "We interrupt this designated initializer to go do our own thing ..."
    return [self init];
}

#pragma mark - NSObject

- (id)init {
    // Why hello there, superclass designated initializer.
    if ((self = [super initWithNibName:@"YourNibHere" bundle:nil])) {

        // We're in a nav controller, so set the title.
        self.navigationItem.title = @"Item Title";

        // "Someone set up us the tab bar!"
        [self setTabBarItem:[[UITabBarItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Item Title" image:[UIImage imageNamed:@"itemIcon.png"] tag:itemTag]];
    }
    return self;
}
```

So ... this is the top **UIViewController** in a **UINavigationController**, which in turn is in a **UITabBarController** at some index. The classic *turducken* of Cocoa view controllers, if you will.

You tap the tab bar item, context changes to the top **UIViewController**, and life is wonderful.

Ahh, but what if you want to programmatically switch to this from a view controller under a different (tab bar) index?

Seems easy enough. Just use `-selectedViewController:` and pass in the **UINavigationController** (*not* the **UIViewController**) you want to switch to. "Mostly harmless."

This works every time ... except I run into a really annoying quirk whenever that **UINavigationController** is tucked away beneath the infamous **More** navigation controller (used by iOS when there are more than five tab bar items in play).

The quirk? When I tap the back button ("More") to pop the **UIViewController** (it's no longer topmost due to the More sitch, y'see), the `imageView` and `textLabel` in the table view cell identifying this tab bar item are *missing*! As in not there. Just an empty cell.

If I scroll the table view cell offscreen and back on, or otherwise move away from and back to the More navigation controller, *then* it appears. :(

Wha' happen? Inquiring minds want to know ...

Comment: It's an old question but I'm having the same issue. Did you find a solution?

Comment: Sadly, not yet. I appreciate the ping all the same.

Answer (score 0):

I made a fix for this. It's not pretty but it's something.

Extend the UITabBarController:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    self.moreNavigationController.delegate = self;
}

- (void)navigationController:(UINavigationController *)navigationController didShowViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController animated:(BOOL)animated {

    //Fix for not showing the selected item in the tableview.
    if ([navigationController.topViewController isKindOfClass:NSClassFromString(@"UIMoreListController")]) {
        [navigationController.topViewController.view.subviews enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:^(id obj, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop) {

            if ([obj isKindOfClass:[UITableView class]]) {
            *stop = YES;
                UITableView *tableView = (UITableView *)obj;
                [tableView reloadData];
            }
        }];
    }
}
```

This way the tableview will reloaded when it becomes visible. You'll see the cell appear in the transition but that's not a problem for me.